# Crear un diccionario jerarquico anidado en python, basado en una lista de resultados

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, recursión

Necesito transformar una lista de datos en un diccionario anidado jerarquico en python. Una estructura (padre - hijo).

estos son mis datos

```
list_data = [
   {
       "id": 2,
       "father_id": 0,
       "desc": "Oficial de Negocios Senior",
       "name": "PEDRO MARTIN SOTO ROSALES"
   },
   {
       "id": 4,
       "father_id": 2,
       "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
       "name": "Adriana Paredez"
   },
   {
       "id": 5,
       "father_id": 2,
       "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
       "name": "Hugo Miranda"
   },
   {
       "id": 3,
       "father_id": 2,
       "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
       "name": "Mario Azcona"
   },
       {
              "id": 6,
              "father_id": 3,
              "desc": "vendedor",
              "name": "Diana Diaz"
          }
  ]
```

Lo he intendado con esta función recursiva, y tengo la estructura correcta, pero me agrega 2 copias más de los tres primeros hijos, que realmente no necesito. el padre raíz es el elemento con father_id = 0

```
def build(loc_key):

    children = {row['id']: {'name': row['name'], 'desc': row['desc'],
                                'child':[]} for row in list_data if row['father_id'] == loc_key}

    data = {}

    for key, value in children.items():
        data[key] = value
        for item in list_data:
            if item['father_id'] == key:
                data[key]['child'].append(build(key))
    return data


print(build(0))
```

Esta es basicamente la estructura que requiero

```
data = {
   2: {'desc': 'Oficial de Negocios Senior',
      'name': 'PEDRO MARTIN SOTO ROSALES', 
      'child': 
          [
          {3: {'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial', 
              'name': 'Mario Azcona', 
              'child': [
                        {6: {'desc': 'vendedor', 
                            'name': 'Diana Diaz', 
                             'child': []}}]}, 
          4: {'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial', 
             'name': 'Adriana Paredez', 
             'child': []}, 
          5: {'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial', 
             'name': 'Hugo Miranda', 
             'child': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu enfoque recursivo me resulta difícil de ver.

He implementado un enfoque iterativo, que tampoco es nada fácil de seguir, pero funciona. Este es el código:

```
def build(lista):
  dict_nodos = {}
  for nodo in lista:
    id = nodo["id"]
    aux = dict(nodo)
    del aux["id"]
    aux["child"] = []
    dict_nodos[id] = aux

  dict_nodos[0] = { "child": [] }

  for id, nodo in dict_nodos.items():
    if id == 0:
      continue
    padre = nodo["father_id"]
    del nodo["father_id"]
    dict_nodos[padre]["child"].append({id: nodo})

  return dict_nodos[0]["child"]
```

Este es un ejemplo de invocación (sobre los datos que proporcionas de ejemplo) y su resultado:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(build(list_data))
```

---

```
[{2: {'child': [{4: {'child': [],
                     'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial',
                     'name': 'Adriana Paredez'}},
                {5: {'child': [],
                     'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial',
                     'name': 'Hugo Miranda'}},
                {3: {'child': [{6: {'child': [],
                                    'desc': 'vendedor',
                                    'name': 'Diana Diaz'}}],
                     'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial',
                     'name': 'Mario Azcona'}}],
      'desc': 'Oficial de Negocios Senior',
      'name': 'PEDRO MARTIN SOTO ROSALES'}}]
```

Y ahora a ver si soy capaz a explicar la idea detrás del código.

El código tiene dos fases:

- En una primera construyo un diccionario sólo con los nodos, aún sin resolver la jerarquía. En ese diccionario las claves son el `id` de cada nodo, y  los valores el resto del diccionario (hago una copia del diccionario completo para después eliminarle la clave `"id"`). De paso añado ya a cada uno un campo `"child"` que contiene una lista vacía.

  Este diccionario me servirá de *lookup table*, para recuperar rápidamente un nodo dado su id.
- En una segunda fase recorro la lista nodos recibida como parámetro y, revisando su campo `"father_id"` añado cada uno de esos nodos a la lista `"child"` del nodo correspondiente (que busco en la *lookup table* anterior). Ya que lo que estoy manejando son referencias, al modificar la lista  `"child"` de un nodo, este cambio se refleja instantáneamente en la *lookup table*.

Para que todo funcione, hace falta insertar manualmente un nodo falso con `id=0` que tenga un campo `"child"` como los demás, pero no tendrá el resto de campos.

Una vez recorrida la lista, la *lookup table* tendrá actualizados todos los nodos, cada uno con su lista de hijos. Basta retornar el campo `"child"` del nodo cuyo id es 0.